# RoR database Error

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, sqlite, terminal, rubygems

Trying to run the database in RoR i have this error

```
Couldn't create database for {"adapter"=>"sqlite3", "pool"=>5, "timeout"=>5000, "database"=>"db/test.sqlite3"}
rake aborted!
Gem::LoadError: Specified 'mysql2' for database adapter, but the gem is not loaded. Add gem 'mysql2' to your Gemfile (and ensure its version is at the minimum required by ActiveRecord).
```

but when i do gem list i get that i have  `mysql2 (0.4.1)`

How can i fix this? and also, why does this happens?

Comment: Why your adapter is `sqlite3`, change it to `mysql2`

Comment: Hi, what's your rails version. I think it's rails bug, Check this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32457657/rails-4-gemloaderror-specified-mysql2-for-database-adapter-but-the-gem-i

Comment: You might wanna check it here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22932282/gemloaderror-specified-mysql2-for-database-adapter-but-the-gem-is-not-loade

Answer (score 1):

Check `/config/database.yml` file

Probably your file contains something like this:

```
development:
  adapter: sqlite3
  pool: 5
  timeout: 5000
  database: db/development.sqlite3
```

Change `sqlite` to `mysql` and add login settings, also check environment (development, production or test)

Answer (score 0):

you need to run `bundle install` as you have already added the gem in the `Gemflle`.Also you need to setup mysql and other libs before installing it.

Comment: Without `bundle install`, will it show in the gem list?

Answer (score 0):

You should include the mysql2 gem into your gemfile and run 'bundle install'.

Also your `config/database.yml` should look something like the below

```
           development:
              adapter: mysql2
              encoding: utf8
              database: my_db_name
              username: root
              password: my_password
```

Here the username and password will be the one you gave at the time of configuring the mysql inyour system